# UseState in useEffect hook with empty array (for socket.io.on)

Tags: socket.io, react-hooks

Currently I have the following code:

```
export default function Chat() {
    const [chat, setChat] = useState({ ID: 0, messages: [] })
    const {socket} = useContext(SocketContext)

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('/chat', (message) => {
            setChat({...chat, messages: [...chat.messages, message] }
            //Some other interaction with variables inside this Chat function (eg: document.getElementById)
        }
    }, [])
 
    return <div>{chat.toDivs()}</div>
}
```

But this doesn't work as expected, because the useEffect always uses the same value of chat. So the result of receiving a message on /chat will always be [message] instead of [...prevMessages, message].

I have searched about this problem and people suggested to use componentDidMount(), but since I'm not using React.Component extendable class, I can't use that method.

Is there any good, simple solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a functional state update so you are updating from the previous state ***and not*** the state value closed over in callback scope.

Don't forget to also unsubscribe when unmounting to clean up resources.

```
const [chat, setChat] = useState({ ID: 0, messages: [] });

useEffect(() => {
  const onChat = (message) => {
    setChat(chat => ({
      ...chat,
      messages: [...chat.messages, message],
    }));
  };

  socket.on('/chat', onChat);

  return () => socket.off('/chat', onChat);
}, []);
```

Comment: How would this work with messages being an object. If I do setChat(chat => {...chat, messages: [...chat.messages, message]}), it doesn't work. Probably a little mistake I'm making here

Comment: @UltraDonut Are you asking if `chat` is an object, with a `messages` array?

Comment: Yes, the chat object has some info too like eg ID

Comment: @UltraDonut I see. Can you update your question to include the *actual* `chat` state shape since it seems it's not just an array?

Comment: @UltraDonut Ok, yeah, what you had in a previous comment looks to be correct. What isn't working with the state update?

Comment: It works now, the parentheses should be around the object. Thanks for helping! Btw, the line of return is called when unmounting right?